# Org background color when collapsed

Tags: org-mode, faces

Lets say I want to color a particular org-level-heading with a code as below

`(set-face-attribute 'org-level-1 ((t (:background "linen") ) ))`

The uncollapsed heading will look like
[image]

However, when the heading collapses we have (my background is white)

[image]

I want it to be such that the entire line is colored by the background color defined by the org-level even when the heading level is collapsed. And I am not sure which variable to edit in order to make that happen.

Secondly, when I add my todos, the heading looks as follows

[image]

I tried to figure out how to force the todo states to take the background color of the heading while keeping rest of their formatting but was unable to do that too.

I have searched for this for a while but was unable to find anything, either knowing the solution or that the solution does not exist would both make me happy. Any solution or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At least for the `Todo` you can modify the backgound color <M-x> customize-group <ret> org-faces <ret>

Comment: The issue there is that I want the color of my org-level heading to overwrite the background color of the todo which means that todo must inherit a different color depending on the org-level and I am not quite sure how to set that up.